# Rerender problems using a4j:ajax in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, richfaces

This could be a very simple one.

We are trying to migrate to `JSF2`, and so far we are using **RF 4.2.0** and **Mojarra 2.1.1**

Everything seemed to be working 100%, very happy. Until we tried the site on `IE9`.

It all still seems to be ok but it just won't rerender more than one id when using a4j:ajax. Here is an example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="idType" value="#{individualApplicationBean.customer.identificationType}" styleClass="default_select w250">
<f:selectItems value="#{selGeneral.defaultOption}" />
<f:selectItems value="#{selIdentificationTypes.identificationTypes}" />
<a4j:ajax event="blur" render="idTypeMsg" listener="#{individualAssetPersonal1.validateIDType}" />
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="idTypeMsg, passportPanel" listener="#{individualAssetPersonal1.validateIDType}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This element works very well in `IE8`, `FireFox` etc. But in `IE9` only the blur works fine. The change works but it only renders the first element, not passportPanel. This happens with all similar elements that try to rerender more than one form element.

When we try to render=@form that is also doing something very strange in `IE9`. The form values get reset etc.

I have now searched most forums and tried a few different things but I just cannot get it to work. And I also don't see anyone else doing what we are.

So could someone please have a look and let me know what we are doing wrong. Any comments on how wrong this approach is, is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth I think I have found a solution. And it was as simple as updating mojarra to 2.1.17.